# AndroidManifest.xml and Strings.xml "File out of sync"

Tags: xml, eclipse, facebook-graph-api

I know this is a common problem and i just dont know how to fix it. While i was importing [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#eclipse) to my project in eclipse, and did what exactly was told in the Facebook devs, i encounterd an error saying "File is out of Sync".

Here is my string.xml

```
  <resources>
  <string name="app_name">my_app_name</string>
  <string name="launcher_name">@string/app_name</string>
  <string name="activity_name">@string/launcher_name</string>

  <string name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId">@string/my_app_id</string>
  </resources>
```

and here is my androidmanifest.xml

```
  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap">
        <intent-filter />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
           android:resource="resource specification"
           android:value="@string/479867658820979" />
    </application>
```

as you can see, i have added the meta-data inside the application tag which was instructed in [facebook devs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#eclipse).

im getting "File out of sync error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to change this:

```
<string name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId">@string/my_app_id</string>
```

to this:

```
<string name="my_app_id">479867658820979</string>
```

in your strings.xml

and in your manifest this:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
       android:resource="resource specification"
       android:value="@string/479867658820979" />
```

to this:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
       android:resource="resource specification"
       android:value="@string/my_app_id" />
```